# Why is a new contributor limited in all the things?

Tags: discussion

I saw this [https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit#:~:text=We%20slow%20down%20new%20user,to%20craft%20a%20good%20answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit#:%7E:text=We%20slow%20down%20new%20user,to%20craft%20a%20good%20answer).
But that does not make any sense, because some people are using ChatGPT, and then all new contributors have to wait for a rate limit of all kinds: no able to comment, no voting, wait 30 minutes to answer, ...?

As a developer, I expect Stack Overflow develops new features to detect ChatGPT answers and prevent it or deduct reputation from answers that receives downvotes. Please do not slow down humans because of AI!!!

Comment: The question and answer posting rate limits already existed before massive posting from LLMs were a thing.

Comment: The limit, however, was shorter than 30 minutes, prior to the LLMs though, @E_net4 .

Comment: *"As a developer I expect StackOverflow develops new features to detect ChatGPT answer and prevent it"* - You are highly encouraged to contribute to such a non-trivial effort.  It's always more productive and effective to *propose* a solution rather than *demand* a solution.

Comment: I tend to agree here, this rate limit in particular and the inability to comment/vote certainly do make it harder to contribute as a newer user. I think the 1 per 30 min throttle is a bit of a lazy solution to the problem.

Comment: *"As a developer I expect StackOverflow develops new features to detect ChatGPT answer"* What makes you think they aren't? Regardless, this time last year [so], and other sites in the community, were being *flooded* with content from tools like CrapGPT and so something had to be done. If you are really keen to contribute that often, then it won't take you that long to earn 125 reputation.

Comment: I presume it is a measure to stop spammers abusing the system. Althgugh I too found it a bit frustrating as a newcomer to be able to pose and answer questions but not to make comments on anything else until I had acquired 50? points. A starting bonus of say 5 comments and instructions to be careful how you use them might be helpful. OTOH I have no feel for how much dross the present posting rules prevent.

Comment: This limit in particular, the 1 per 30 minutes, was meant to be a temporary solution to hold back the tide of rapid gpt answers from new users. Maybe it's still needed, maybe it's not, but i find it a bit problematic that it's still active after plenty of research has been done showing that it's adversely affecting the rate at which things get answered. Surely, in 6 months, *something* could have been done to provide a better solution to this... but... no, chatbot work is more important.

Comment: It's hard to write a two good answers to non-trivial problems (and almost all trivial problems will be a duplicate) in half an hour.

Comment: The author has submitted 7 answers, not a single one has been well received, and all were submitted within a very short timeframe to one another. I have no suggestions or feedback if that reception is justified since I know little about the tag topics in question. Submitting 5 high quality answers in a single day is  tough since that requires finding 5 high quality questions in a day. If even 25% of those answers were legitimately upvoted the rate limit would essentially no longer be a problem

Comment: @MartinBrown The reputation requirement for posting comments is, primarily, to prevent spam in comments, which would be rampant and *much* harder to moderate if users with no reputation were permitted to comment generally. Unfortunately, your proposal of permitting 5 comments to new users *effectively* removes the restriction on spammers, while retaining the restriction on users who are real users. Spammers can and do create multiple accounts, sometimes thousands of accounts. If they were permitted to post 5 comments per account, then they would just create more accounts to get more comments.

Comment: I've closed this question as unclear/needs details, because you're asking "why" the limit exists and the reason why is explicitly stated on [the page which you link to in the help center](//stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit) (i.e., that it was increased to 30 minutes in order to slow down posting of AI-generated content answers). Thus, it's unclear to me what you're really asking here. [Note: this closure was specifically because it's unclear to me what you're asking *here*. A discussion about if the answer rate limit for users with < 125 reputation should be 30 minutes would be fine.]

Comment: Yes, please. I don't want to upset people due to my frustration. I just don't want to be constrained by the shortcomings of AI usage.

Comment: @CamHoang - If you want this question reopened, you will have to [edit], to adjust Makyen's feedback.

Comment: @Mayken thank you for the clarification - that makes perfect sense. I hadn't realised you were targeted by spammers to quite such an extent.

Comment: @MartinBrown you should say "we", not "you". You're part of the family too.

Answer (score -3):

It is annoying to be limited in how you can interact on the site because of the actions of others. However, if you're really coming up against the 30 minute time making multiple answers, you shouldn't have this problem for too long since your answers will be upvoted and you'll find yourself out of the rep cutoff pretty quickly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: I mean it kinda does. OP is saying its annoying to have to wait 30 minutes to post an answer. And I am somewhat disagreeing, saying that the problem solves itself (if you're really hitting that limit providing good answers, then you'll get upvoted out of the cutoff)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Also a bit confused as @Thom A 's upvoted comment is basically what I'm saying here:
'If you are really keen to contribute that often, then it won't take you that long to earn 125 reputation'

Comment: I don’t understand the reaction to this answer, it’s essentially saying, the rate limit isn’t a problem if you submit high quality contributions.

Comment: @securityhound I agree. The solution to the problem of not having the required reputation to post comments is to find a good question where you know the answer and answer it well.  Quality not quantity. I do think newbies might reasonably be given a small number of comments to make - they are much less demanding than answers (and any spam immediately stamped on). Am I alone in regularly falling foul of the 5 minute rule on editing comments?

Comment: My problem is this: _"you shouldn't have this problem for too long since your answers will be upvoted"_ No. Lots of answers don't get upvoted. Let's not presume that that's to be expected.